# Why can I not encode const structs?

Tags: c#, struct, constants

I wish to encode hard coded value of a const Point struct.

Why does the compiler not allow neither internal, nor arbitrary structs to be replaced during compilation? Since the internal bitwise representation can be established at compile time (in both cases), there is no apparent reason for the restriction.

My question is: Is there a way to hard-code a predefined set of bytes in c# that can be interpreted at compile time as the appropriate type, since all structs have a predetermined memory outline.

**EDIT:**

To clarify:  Compile time means C# -> IL byte-code as stored in the output assembly.

The use case example:

```
public void Draw(Bitmap bmp, Point Location = new Point(0,0)) // invalid
```

This is an error because the `new Point(0,0)` cannot be evaluated at compile time. I can pass in `int X = 0, int Y = 0` or the nullable `Point? Location = null` and generate the struct inside of the method, or Overload the method without the optional parameters and call the main method passing in the default values, but that technique incurs a performance penalty in terms of the extra method calls required.

This may not be appropriate for all structs, since the constructor could  rely on, or change, external state or randomness.

### FINAL EDIT:

This is now possible. Making the question moot. Yay.

The issue was the incorrect belief that the `new` keyword always implied heap allocation or dynamic stack allocation, with constant arguments neither case was true.

Comment: Not all compilation happens on your machine. There's a JIT process on other machines, too, and not all of those machines will have the same representation of bytes (think big endian vs little endian, but there can be other variations, too).

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn,  All CIL/MSIL interpreters and compilers in order to be standards compliant MUST interpret all multi-byte data structures as little endian(The only exception is an unsafe pointer passed natively on a big endian system).  See http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf, Section V.1.1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the underlying reason for the question has been finally resolved.

Answer (score 3):

> Why does the compiler not allow neither internal, nor arbitrary structs to be replaced during compilation? Since the internal bitwise representation can be established at compile time (in both cases), there is no apparent reason for the restriction.

All not-implemented features are not implemented for the same reason. To be implemented, a feature must be thought of, judged to be appropriate, designed, specified, implemented, tested, documented and shipped. All those things must happen. For your proposed feature, none of them happened. Therefore, no feature.

Programming language designers are not required to provide a justification for why a feature was not implemented. Rather, the people who want the feature are required to provide a reason why programming language designers should spend their valuable time implementing a feature that you want.

The C# design process is open, and the compiler source code is available. **Why have you not designed and implemented the feature?**  If it is fair for you to ask the designers that question, it's fair for them to ask it of you!  You're a computer programmer; get busy programming computers and build the feature if you think it is worthwhile, and then convince the language team to accept your pull request. If you don't think it is worth your time to do that, well, probably the language designers feel the same way.

> My question is: Is there a way to hard-code a predefined set of bytes in c# that can be interpreted at compile time as the appropriate type, since all structs have a predetermined memory outline.

I'm not sure what you mean by "at compile time"; can you clarify?

There are ways to store byte arrays in an assembly, sure. Make a C# program with a byte array initialized to all constant values and ildasm the assembly; you'll see the code that the C# compiler generates to get the byte array image out of the metadata and into the array.

You could implement similar shenanigans to get a byte array, fix the array in place, and then use unsafe pointer magic to reinterpret the array bytes as struct bytes.  That sounds extraordinarily dangerous, and might mess up the performance of the garbage collector. I would not wish to do so myself, but you seem pretty keen on this feature, so go for it and report back what you find out!

Alternatively, C++/CLI probably implements the feature you want; I've never used it but that seems like the sort of thing it would do. You could write a little program in C++/CLI that does what you want, and then either (1) use that program's assembly as a dependency of your assembly, (2) compile it as a netmodule link it in to your assembly via the usual netmodule linking gear (yuck) or (3) deduce how they implemented the feature and then do the same.

Comment: If you're interested in using pointer magic in the way Eric describes, you might find the [reference source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/bitconverter.cs,205) for `BitConverter.ToInt32` to be of interest.

Comment: I removed this as the answer since this does not answer the asked question as asked.  I want to specify a default value to a function  that is a struct in nature, required at compile time.If this is not possible, say so.  The is a question about default values for methods.

Comment: "I'm not sure what you mean by "at compile time"; can you clarify?" What is the difference between  `Point Location = new Point(0,0)` and `int a = new Int32(5)` or `int a=5`?  absolutely nothing but semantics. No pointers or byte arrays should be needed. One type is internal the other other is not. Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a struct into byte array and encode a byte array. It may work like this: (please compile and fix any errors (typing through mobile))

Suppose your struct is:

```
public struct TestStruct
{
 public int x;
 public string y;
}

public byte[] GetTestByte(TestStruct c)
{
    var intGuy = BitConverter.GetBytes(c.x);
    var stringGuy = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(c.y);
    var both = stringGuy.Concat(intGuy).Concat(new byte[1]).ToArray();
    return both;
}
```

Now you can encode a byte array like:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
```

There is no direct way to encode a struct. Its a value type at best and probably there as legacy for C and C++

Comment: The question was regarding hard-coded structs.  I up-voted your response, since it will be most likely be helpful to anyone searching for this topic later on.